# TextInput placeholder is not taking fontWeight

Tags: react-native, react-native-textinput

I have a TextInput field with placeholder given. On load the placeholder text should be shown as `fontWeight:"normal"` and when the user enters a value in textbox - the letter gets in `fontWeight:"bold"` but when the textbox is again empty - the placeholder should revert to `fontWeight:"normal"`. Currently, despite changing and updating the state, the placeholder still takes `"fontWeight:bold"`, once the user types and removes the text from TextInput field.

I tried using placeholderStyle, but this is not for my scenario, I dont want to change the style, only font weight.

```
  <TextInput
    style={
      !searchText
        ? [styles.autoCompleteInputStyle, styles.placeholderText]
        : [styles.autoCompleteInputStyle, styles.searchedText]
    }
    underlineColorAndroid="transparent"
    placeholder="Search item"
    placeholderTextColor="#505050"
    autocorrect={false}
    value={searchText}
    onChangeText={searchTextValue => this.onChangeText(searchTextValue)}
    clearButtonMode="while-editing"
    returnKeyType="search"
  />
```

Style for autocompleteTextInput

```
  autoCompleteInputStyle: {
    flexDirection: "row",
    height: 40,
    borderStyle: "solid",
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderColor: "#cccccc",
    fontSize: 18,
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: "center",
    marginRight: 14,
    marginBottom: 20,
    paddingLeft: 40,
    color: "#000000",
    borderRadius: 2,
    lineHeight: 21,
    fontFamily: fontStyleFlightCard.fontFamily
  },
    searchedText: {
      fontWeight: "bold"
    },
    placeholderText: {
      fontWeight: "normal"
    },
```

I expect placeholder should be in normal fontWeight, and when the user inputs text, it should be in bold. Whenever the user types and removes the text from TextInput, placeholder text changes to normal fontWeight.

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue is !searchText.
Make sure !searchText is `true` when blank.
You might need to make it something like

```
searchText === '' ? placeholderText : searchedText
```

Comment: I tried doing the same with the condition, but fontWeight is not getting changed from bold to normal, when there is no text available.

Answer (score 0):

i've got it working by changing `searchTextValue` to `searchText` under `onChangeText` prop.

you can view an example i've made [here](https://snack.expo.io/@kenmistry/placeholder-fontweight-test).